# using methods in java programming

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
public class ProcessNumbers
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer between 6 and 12, inclusive: ") ;
        int num = in.nextInt() ;
        System.out.print(num) ;
        System.out.println();
        boolean result = shouldProcess(num);
        processInput(result) ;
    }
    public static boolean shouldProcess(int n)
    {
        if (n>=6 && n<12)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    public static void processInput(boolean result2)
    {
        if (result2 == true)
        {
            int sum = findSum(num) ; 
            public static void findSum(int num)
            {
                int sum = 0 ;
                for (int i = 1; i <=num; i++0)
                {
                    sum +=i ;
                    System.out.println(sum) ;
                }     
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Number is outside of acceptable range") ;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

With this code I am trying to get the user to input a number. The computer will read in this number and return a boolean value in the method shouldProcess if the given number is between 6 and 12(inclusive). If it is not within these two numbers it will return false. Next I have made the method processINput which uses the first method shouldProcess to deterermine if it can compute the sum, only if shouldProcess returns true.

I am running into these errors in my shouldProcess method block when I am trying to compute the sum

```
 [File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 34, Column: 10] illegal start of     expression
[File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 34, Column: 17] illegal start of expression
[File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 34, Column: 23] ';' expected
[File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 34, Column: 41] '.class' expected
[File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 34, Column: 44] ';' expected
[File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 36, Column: 21] ';' expected
[File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 37, Column: 38] ')' expected
[File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 37, Column: 39] ';' expected
[File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 40, Column: 37] ';' expected
[File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 43, Column: 6] 'else' without 'if'
[File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 47, Column: 3] reached end of file while parsing
[File: /ProcessNumbers.java Line: 48, Column: 1] illegal character: \26
```

Comment: You have a nested method? `public static void findSum(int num)` I don't think you can do that in Java.

Comment: how do I change that then, that must be my error

Comment: @javahelp That method must be moved outside of the `public static void processInput` method.

Comment: do I need to return a value from shoudlProcess since findSum only computes if shouldProcess returns true

Comment: Paste ur code in Notepad++ and click on the brackets to make sure that they close properly.  And use code beautifier to clean up ur code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a function `findSum` inside a function `processInput` which is not allowed and that function is actually not required. Check this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProcessNumbers
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer between 6 and 12, inclusive: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print(num);
        System.out.println();
        boolean result = shouldProcess(num);
        processInput(result, num); // passing the result and num
    }

    public static boolean shouldProcess(int n) 
    {
        if (n>=6 && n<12)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        } 
    }

    public static void processInput(boolean result2, int num) // added int num argument
    {
        if (result2 == true)
        {
            //int sum = findSum(num);

            //public static void findSum(int num) // not allowed
            //{
                int sum = 0; // missed the semi-colon
                for (int i = 1; i <=num; i++)
                {
                      sum +=i;
                }
                System.out.println(sum); // missed the semi-colon
            //}
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Number is outside of acceptable range");
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: this code is good but for the input of 10 i should get the output for sum to be 55 however it comes out to be 1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
55

Answer (score 2):

These are compiler errors from when your code is trying to compile, often this is to do with incorrect syntax such as `System.out.println(sum)` has no `;` to indicate the end of the line.

There are also a few other thing you might want to change, instead of having a shouldProcees method and a processInput method you would be better moving the if statement in shouldProcess up to your main method and determining whether to processInput there. Then you can simply have `if (n>=6 && n<=12) { processInput();` which will also let you clean up the process input method becuase it will already know result is true and you can remove the `if (result2 == true)`.

I don't think you can have nested methods in java so you'll either have to move findSum into a seperate method or just remove the findSum method and do the calculation straight in the processInput method.

You might want to consider using an IDE which often can compile on the go and detect syntax errors.

Comment: i can not download those on school computers

Comment: You may want to consider asking your teacher or IT technician to install them, massive benefits and very helpful in teaching and developing good habits

Answer (score 1):

You should probably indent your if/else and method blocks, just to check for braces lining up correctly. I think you still have a closing brace - } - missing at the end.

For example, your code should look something like this:

```
public class... {
    public static void main... {
        if... {
            if... {
            ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can keep track of your braces very easily.

Comment: yes thanks for the tip I have done that in my program

Comment: No you haven't, because there's an extra opening brace. You need an extra brace at the end of your program.

Comment: This is the error that gave you "Reached the end of file while parsing"

Comment: he probably means that he did now

Comment: I don't see the change. I'll edit it myself....